# How to escape single quotes in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I come from MySQL and the below query doesn't work in Sybase. How should I escape single quotes?

```
UPDATE Animals SET NAME = 'Dog\'s friends' WHERE uid = 12
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If working with Sybase, having got used to MySQL which more database users have experience you may soon discover you are unable to escape single quotes with backslash in.

So how do you escape quotes in Sybase? In fact, in Sybase SQL the single quote acts as the escape character.

See below for an example UPDATE statement in both “languages”:

**MySQL**

```
UPDATE Animals SET NAME = 'Dog\'s friends' WHERE uid = 12
```

**Sybase**

```
UPDATE Animals SET NAME = 'Dog''s friends' WHERE uid = 12
```

I’m not entirely sure this makes sense to me (especially as it looks like a double quote) but there you go!

Comment: Using two single quotes to escape one is the SQL standard and basically all DBMS support that (even MySQL when configured to behave like a normal DBMS)

Comment: When coming from MySQL to a proper database, you're going to find a lot of things that are new. :)

Comment: Is there any better solution for maybe having something like `''''''''`

Comment: Thanks. You save my day

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to escape quotes :

```
CREATE FUNCTION "ESCAPE_QUOTES"(in a_string long varchar) 
returns long varchar
begin
  return replace(a_string, '''', '''''');
end
```