# Sybase select with '

Tags: t-sql, select, sybase

I have a query:

```
select "'"+full_name+"'" from  Names
```

In sybase, this works fine if there is no ' in the full_name column.
If a single quote is present in the string in the name the rest of the characters are considered as junk. ex. select 'Mc'donald' from Names. could you please help.

Comment: It works okay in my installation (server: ASE 15.0.2, clients: sqsh, isql). What server and client(s) are you using? Perhaps first try with another (simpler) client, eg Sybase isql. Then consider how you're consuming those results; is some code/ a tool making assumptions about balanced quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The escape character in Sybase appears to be the apostrophe (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528455/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-sybase)), so you would want to replace all apostrophe's in the Full_name field with two apostrophes. I think this should work:

```
Select "'" + replace(full_name,"'","''") + "'" from Names
```

Hope this helps!